# How to edit admin panel order view buttons?

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

Please can you explain how can we edit admin panel buttons (eg: back, edit, cancel) in order view and how can we know that where these buttons are comes from.

Answer (score 2):

buttons are found here:

```
core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/View.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Magento code reference, where you can browse through the connections between different parts of the code: http://docs.magentocommerce.com/
Without more information about what you want to do, I can just give you one more hint (although I have not used Magento in several years): it will help you greatly to understand the Zend framework and how the class loading (auto loading) procedure works.

Comment: i ma trying to remove search button from sales->orders